# Propotion test vs T-test

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, z-test

Proportion test - Helps to identify if there is significant difference in proportion across the samples.(i.e. the values are in proportion and denominator is in sample size of entire proportion)
Example :

- Group A
  Proportion of Male - 40/100
- Group B
  Proportion of Male - 50/120

So Ideal scenario, I'd perform Z- Proportion test to validate my results.

I'm clear with the ideas.

**Problem Statement :**

Estimate if the Revenue generated across the Group Aa & Group Bb is significant.

Target Column: Revenue(Price*qty) Generation at Customer level.

> H0 : Null Hypothesis = Proportion(p1)% = proportion(p2%) --> No significant difference

> H1 : Null Hypothesis = Proportion(p1)% != proportion(p2%) --> Significant difference

Group A(All Products) - 200 Unique customers "Total Revenue - 4000$ "

> Revenue Generation of specific subgroup

Group Aa(Specific Product)- 23 Unique Customers "Revenue - 620$ "

> | Cust Id | Revenue |
> | --- | --- |
> | 11 | 4.2 |
> | 12 | 4.2 |
> | 13 | 4.2 |
> | 14 | 4.2 |
> | 15 | 8.4 |

- Here I'm calling it biased stating 4.2 is been repeated the most because the quantity of the purchase is 1. So it means 4.2*1 resulting with 4.2$.
- Proportion tells %  of how much specific product generates me revenue compared to all other products in the Group A.

= 620 / 5000
( Group Aa Revenue of specific product / Group A total Revenue of all products)

> Proportion P1= 12.39 %

Similarly :

Group B(All Products) - 203 Unique Customers "Total Revenue - 4000$ "

> Revenue Generation of specific subgroup

Group Bb(Specific Product from All Products)-20 Unique Customers "Revenue - 435$ "

> | Cust Id | Revenue |
> | --- | --- |
> | 21 | 8.4 |
> | 22 | 4.2 |
> | 23 | 4.2 |
> | 24 | 4.2 |
> | 25 | 8.4 |

- Proportion tells %  of how much specific product generates me revenue compared to all other products in the Group B.

= 435/ 4000
( Group Bb Revenue of specific product / Group B total Revenue of all products)

> Proportion p2= 10.88%

In this case the difference is 1.50% to verify that it is significant.

> Should I prefer the 2 proportion Z- test because we are trying to
> find whether the difference is proportion is significant (or)  t-test
> to check the mean difference across Group Aa & Group Bb.

Is it okay to use a proportion test even though the denominator/base is not in sample size.

Comment: How are the specific subgroups Aa and Bb (each of size 20) chosen? At random or by looking at the same data to be used in your test. Also, your use of the word 'bias' does not seem standard. Please explain what you mean. At the end you ask, "Is it okay to use proportion test even ... if the denominator/base is not in sample size."  If this means what I think it does, the answer is _absolutely not OK._ // To clarify, please list the two groups of 20 'revenue' scores, make it clear how groups were obtained, and make it clear what you want to test, giving null and alternative hypotheses.

Comment: @BruceET thanks a lot for the comments. I've edited and updated the question. Kindly let me know if its clear enough. thanks

Comment: @BruceET Any suggestion is welcomed. Thanks